# Rotation Image button in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rotation, components

I would love to know if there is package for rotation image **button** or some best practice for this issue.

for Example in Office Word below:

[Before Rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H35ls.png)

[After Rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqbLG.png)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can apply inline style

```
let degreeValue = 10;

...

<Image {...yourProps} style={{transform: [{ rotate: `${degreeValue}deg` }]}} />
```

Comment: I need it with a draggable button

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use transform in the style of the Image component.
`90deg` is just an example to rotate this image.

```
style={{ transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}] }}
```

Comment: I need it with a draggable button